# Mongodb simple query on indexed field is slow

Tags: mongodb

I'm fairly new to mongodb, I've been trying to work out what I need to do to improve this query and I can't seem to find anything that fixes it. I've tried adding an index on the field but it still takes ~24 seconds to lookup a user by email address on a dataset of about one and a half a million users. The query is simply:

```
UserModel.findOne({
    'emails.address': emailAddr
}, {
    _id: true,
    account_status: true,
    local_auth: true,
    personas: {$elemMatch: {is_default: true}}
}, function (err, user) { });
```

There is an index on the _id field and another one on the emails.address field. Here's the output from the profiler:

```
{ "op" : "query", "ns" : "dbname", "query" : { "emails.address" : "test@ggsfg.com" }, "ntoreturn" : 1, "ntoskip" : 0, "nscanned" : 1560155, "keyUpdates" : 0, "numYield" : 23, "lockStats" : { "timeLockedMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(47843876), "w" : NumberLong(0) }, "timeAcquiringMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(23600947), "w" : NumberLong(7) } }, "nreturned" : 0, "responseLength" : 20, "millis" : 24252, "ts" : ISODate("2014-01-26T17:47:00.658Z"), "client" : "", "allUsers" : [ ], "user" : "" }
```

The mongoose schema looks like (it has a _id object field as well with its own index on the root of the schema, and there is also another _id in the emails collection):

```
{
    ... other fields ...
    emails: [
      {
        address: {
            type: String,
            match: /^(?:[\w\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]+@(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-](?!\.)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-](?!$)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]?)|(?:\[(?:(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\]))$/,
            index: true
        },
        is_default: {
            type: Boolean,
            require: true,
            'default': false
        },
        added_at: {
            type: Date,
            'default': Date.now
        },
        verified_at: {
            type: Date
        },
        verification_key: {
            type: String
        }
      }
    ],
    ... other fields ...
}
```

If anyone could point out what I need to do to get this query working fast I'd be extremely grateful.

Edit:
OK, it was the way I was constructing the query that was causing the indexed field not to be used. I've changed it to this now and it works perfectly

```
UserModel.findOne({
    emails: {
    "$elemMatch": {
        address: emailAddr
    }
}
```

Comment: What do your docs look like and what index did you add?

Comment: I've added the relevant schema parts to the original post now. There is an index on the root _id and an index on the emails.address field which doesn't appear to be doing much.

Comment: According to your profile output this query looks to be scanning all the entries in your collection: `("nscanned" : 1560155)`. Can you check the index definitions from the `mongo` shell (`db.collection.getIndexes()`) to see if there actually is an index created on `emails.address`? The output of [`explain(true)`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) for your query in the `mongo` shell would also be much more helpful than the profile info.

Comment: @Stennie The output of getIndexes() is: http://pastebin.com/mVySjf4N and the output of explain(true) is http://pastebin.com/yFLVbg5R

Comment: I see you worked out the problem in your edit -- FYI, you can post your own explanation as an answer. Also, the `explain(true)` I meant would have been: `db.users.find({ "emails.address" : "fdsfsig@dfdfsf.com" }).explain(true)` (the `true` option explains all plans considered, rather than only the winning plan).